# Send email with Flask-Email

Tags: python, flask

I have tried all, I have tried the old example that I have seen here in stackoverflow and nothing works. The code that I am using:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

 # configuramos los parámetros de conexión al servidor de correo
 app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'mail.test.com'
 app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
 app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
 app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'no-reply@test.com'
 app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'no-reply'

 # creamos un objeto "Mail" que nos permitirá enviar correos
 mail = Mail(app)

 @app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      # obtenemos los datos del formulario
      name = 'Jesus'
      email = 'no-reply@test.com'
      message = 'Test'

      # creamos un mensaje de correo
      msg = Message(f'Mensaje de {name}', sender=email, recipients=['test@test.com'])
      msg.body = message
      mail.send(msg)

    return str(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

It does not display me any error, I have added try catch() and no error displays so I wonder what I am doing wrong? I never receive the email, I am sending or testing it in localhost maybe it could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: did you fix identation in your code and then run it ?

Comment: Yes and it is not because it compiles

Comment: Does `mail.send` return anything?  If so, please [edit] the question to show us.

Answer (score 0):

While not flask email, this is the system I used for the emails on my last flask site. Also, make sure you make a google application if you're using Gmail as your normal password will not work.

I have used a env file to store my passwords tho you can just replace that with text if you want

```py
from matplotlib.style import context
import smtplib
import email
from email.message import EmailMessage
import os
import ssl


password = os.environ["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
users =[""]
fromuser = os.environ["GMAIL_USER"]
touser = users  
subject = "stuff stuff"
body = " stuff stuff"
em = EmailMessage()
em.set_content(body)
em['From'] = fromuser
em['To'] = touser
em['Subject'] = subject 
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login(fromuser, password)
    server.send_message(em)
    print("Email sent")
    server.quit()
```